# Android URI in OnClickListener

Tags: android, youtube, uri, android-videoview, onclicklistener

Hi guy's i have a problem with Android...
This is a part of my code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
TableLayout MainTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_table);
JSONArray Jobj = new JSONArray(result_set);
String url_img = null;
String url_video = null; //MUST CONTAINS THE URL OF MY VIDEO

for (int i = 0; i < Jobj.length(); i++) {
    TableRow row = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
    row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    row.setPadding(0, 14, 2, 14);

    JSONObject titoli = Jobj.getJSONObject(i);
    Integer id = titoli.getInt("id_video");
    String titolo = titoli.getString("nome_video");
    String immagini = titoli.getString("video_img");
    String video_url = titoli.getString("url_video"); 
    /* video_url : this is the variable that i change (and contains the relative path that i obtains parsing json array) */

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(immagini);

    Pattern v = Pattern.compile("^/video/[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]");
    Matcher vm = v.matcher(video_url);

    // Path video
    if (vm.matches() == false) {
        url_video = path_youtube + video_url; // SECOND ERROR HERE
    } else if (vm.matches() == true) {
        url_video = path_an_tv + video_url; // SECOND ERROR HERE
    }

    // Path image
    if (m.matches() == false) {
        url_img = path + immagini;
    } else if (m.matches() == true) {
        url_img = immagini;
    }

    ImageView img = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    img.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    img.setMaxHeight(140);
    img.setMaxWidth(140);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(url_img).getContent());
    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    final TextView txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    txt.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    txt.setLayoutParams(params);
    txt.setTextSize(18);
    txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    txt.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    txt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    txt.setId(id);
    txt.setText(titolo);
    txt.setClickable(true);

    row.addView(img);
    row.addView(txt);
    MainTable.addView(row);

    txt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url_video))); 
                   /* FIRST ERROR HERE, url_video contains the absolute url of my video*/
        }
    });
}
```

When i try compile my project an error occours:

*Cannot refer to a non final variable url_video inside a innner class defined in a different method...*

If I change url video into `final` another error occours:

*The final local variable cannot be assigned. it must be blank and not using a compound assignment*

How I can fix it ?

**UPDATE I FIX IT REPLACING WITH THIS:**

```
final TextView txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext()); 
     txt.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL );
     txt.setLayoutParams(params); txt.setTextSize(18); txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
     txt.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD); txt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); 
     txt.setId(id); txt.setTag(url_video); txt.setText(titolo); txt.setClickable(true); 

     row.addView(img);
     row.addView(txt);  
     MainTable.addView(row);

     txt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
      public void onClick(View v) {
       startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse((String) txt.getTag())));
      }
     });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define it in class level `private String video_url;`

You can't access a variable defined within `onCreate()` within `OnClick()` Because the scope of oncreate is over when you get a click. So you must keep the variable scope alive.

**UPDATE**

Yeah, Its simple,

```
public class YourClass {

    private String video_url;

    public void OnCreate()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: dont forget to remove your String video_url; within oncreate

Comment: Arju, your question doesn't work !

I generate my layout dinamically, with this function i want to show a list of video, and when the video title was pressed the function "onclicklistener" must start 1 new activity, open youtube, show my video using the correct link (url_video)...

Answer (score 0):

Just make this an instance variable

```
String url_video = null;
```

That is define this inactivity.